# Animate var div object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have a class defined var "bar" attributed to a certain div with no ID nor CLASS.

```
bar.style.width = progress+"%";
```

Is there a way I can make "bar" var  div animate using jquery?

```
.animate({width:progress+"%"},90);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bar` looks like a dom element reference... you need to get the jQuery object to call `animate(...)`

so

```
$(bar).animate({width:progress+"%"},90);
```